# Creating multiple variable conditions

Tags: if-statement, case, tableau-api, calculation

Here’s the overview of my problem.

I have a column titled product and it’s filtered down to show 5 product types in the columns. The rows show all customers (2000). And the measure values show a quantity for the products. I want to create a calculated field that says: if >1 product has a balance greater than 0, then true else false. And I want this to appear for every customer. Basically, I want to filter out customers that only have a balance for one product type. I’ve tried several different statements, but can’t calibrate it correctly to match what I’m trying to do here. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Superstore data, I made the following which should work for your use case.

Create a LOD calc on customer and count distinct the amount of products they have. Adding a greater than converts this to T/F. In my example I did 2 just to illustrate so adjust accordingly.

```
{fixed [Customer Name] : countd([Category])}>2
```

Filter for True to capture just the customers with 3 categories of products.

[image]

Comment: Bernardo, thank you for the reply, this was very helpful. One other question to pick your brain. In the super store set, the number of sub categories is three: furniture, office supplies, and technology. In my data set, I have over 100 products but only want 5 to appear so I filtered out the irrelevant 95. However, when I use your calculation, it seems to ignore the filter. And so, the calculation searches for all sub categories. Is there a way I could limit this to just focus on the five sub categories I’d like?

Comment: LOD Calcs have different filter orders. For FIXED, set any filters to CONTEXT and they will reflect in the data. See this for more information.  https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.htm